Does defeating enemies quickly contribute to Artemis hunts?
Occasionally Artemis appear will appear during a run and assist with defeating enemies. This seems similar to the Thanatos fight from Hades 1 where you would get a reward for defeating more enemies in a time limit, but there isn't a kill counter for the Artemis hunts.
Does defeating enemies quickly have any benefit in an Artemis hunt? If not, is there some other special way I should be defeating enemies?

Artemis hunt event works differently than the Thanatos fight event in the first game. She's mainly here to help, although her appearance also means a lot more waves of enemies will appear. Defeating more enemies than her, or ending the fight slowly or quickly won't have any effect on the outcome, as she will still always stay after the fight and give you an unaffected reward choice: choosing one of her 3 boons.
As for the Thanatos fight equivalent in Hades II:

 You get a similar system when encountering Nemesis, where one of the possible events with her is you two fighting to beat the most enemies possible.

